# Is it possible to overload the indexing operator[] to return bits from an integer?

Tags: c++, operators, operator-overloading, bitwise-operators

I am not sure whether this is possible because as far as I know, references cannot refer to individual bits in an integer, but I am curious to know whether there is a technique that will enable the following effect.

```
int z = 0x1234;
z[0] = 1; //set the most significant bit of z.
uint8_t bit = z[30] //get the index 30 bit of z, counting from the left.
```

If I cannot have `z[0] = 1`, I wonder if it is at least possible to be able to extract bits using the overloading operation.

Comment: operator overloading does not work for builtin types, but you can create your own integer class and overload [] for your class?

Comment: Why use the index operator at all? That would needlessly obscure the code, since it's not the normal use of indexing operators. Better provide a function that explicitly states what it's doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not directly. You can either write a wrapper over `int` or use a `std::bitset`.

Comment: Can I define a wrapper that behaves in every way like an int except with a different name and this operation enabled?

Comment: @merlin2011: You can't imitate `int` exactly. For example, the conversion from `int` to `long` is built-in, and thus it can participate in a conversion chain that includes a user-defined conversion. The conversion from your type to `long` will be user-defined, and therefore would run up against the limit of one user-defined conversion in any chain. You can give your type all the same operators as `int`, AFAIK it's only the conversions that will behave differently from the guaranteed behavior of `int`.

Comment: @merlin2011 yes, you can provide implicit conversions from and to ints for that wrapper. However, this is seldom a good idea, since typos and logical errors that otherwise would have been remarked by the compiler could become legal code and introduce hard-to-track bugs.

Comment: @ArneMertz surely if you want the type to behave as an integer,these implicit conversions are desirable? I cannot think of a situation where they would not be.

Comment: @merlin2011 I started implementing something for you but decided to recommend `bitset` instead. You can convert it to an `unsigned long`, or `unsigned long long` with `C++11`.

Comment: @juanchopanza the downside would be that in prsence of that type not only any object of that type would behave like an int, but also any int could behave like that type, meaning you'd get the implicit conversion in places where you would not even think about it. In fact, not only ints but also bools etc. could behave like that type in unforseen places. However, using `operator[]` on ints directly won't be possible at all, because it's a member function and the ints won't be implicitly converted to the wrapper to call the operator on it.

Comment: @juanchopanza: one could reasonably argue that the implicit conversions *of int* aren't desirable (but we're stuck with them), and therefore what you want is to behave like `int` except in respect of conversions ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot overload operators for built-in types. Overloaded operators must include at least one user-defined type (i.e. a class or union type).

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to wrap `int`, you could do it something like this:

```
class bitval {
    int &val;
    unsigned int mask;
  public:
    bitval(int &i, int idx) : val(i), mask(((unsigned int)(INT_MAX) + 1) >> idx) {}
    bitval &operator=(int i)  {
        if (i) {
            val |= mask;
        } else {
            val &= ~mask;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    operator bool() const {
        return val & mask;
    }
};

class bit {
    int &val;
  public:
    bit(int &i) : val(i) {}
    bitval operator[](int idx) { return bitval(val, idx); }
};
```

Then the syntax would be:

```
int z = 0x1234;
bit(z)[0] = 1;
uint8_t b = bit(z)[30];
```

Btw, C++ programmers usually refer to the *least* significant bit as bit 0, not the *most* significant bit, so `mask(1 << idx)` might make things less confusing for them.